# extracting data for variables in list of dataframes

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have a list of dataframes (dataframe1, dataframe2,dataframe3 ..dataframe(n)). All the dataframes have a single column named "Patient_ID". Now I'm trying to get the metadata associated with the patient ids using:

```
  lists_of_metadata <- data.frame()
  
  for (i in 1:length(all_lists))  
  {lists_of_metadat[i] <- all_metadata2[(all_metadata2$Patient_ID %in% all_lists[[i]][[1]]),]}
```

This is however not working. I have also tried another way, which is also returning nothing:

```
lapply(all_lists, function(x) {all_metadata2[(all_metadata2$Patient_ID %in%
                                                 (names(x)[ grep("Patient_ID", names(x))])),]
  } )
```

I want to return lists_of_metadata file that will contain the extracted metadata, and also preserving the dataframe names I have in the all_lists file. I have been stuck on this for a while and would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you want to create a list containing all unique patient IDs?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the dataframes in a list and then you can use `lapply` as -

```
all_lists <- list(dataframe1, dataframe2,dataframe3, ..dataframe(n))

lists_of_metadat <- lapply(list_data, function(x)  
                  all_metadata2[all_metadata2$Patient_ID %in% x$Patient_ID,])
```